# $watch only called after minimum requirements

Tags: angularjs, input, field, watch, minimum

I noticed that when I set

```
ng-minlength=6
```

to my input field, $watch only reacts once it meets this criteria, or any other requirements I set for it. How can I get it so that $watch is called before?

http://plnkr.co/edit/98yReat71BHsEN83Tuj8?p=preview

Notice how only after you type more than 6 characters does the data bind show.

Comment: why do you need to $watch the variable if the value is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS, by default, doesn't allow invalid values to change the ViewModel.

However, Angular introduced - in version 1.3 (I believe) - an [`ngModelOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) directive to fine-tune how `ngModel` works. Among other things, this directive gives an option to `allowInvalid` values:

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-minlength="6" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lNUOaWADpScYNWHqRhZJ?p=preview)